# nvinitx.dll not found in Visual Studio 2012 (C++-Project)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dll, nvidia

I want to compile the following code, which seems to be valid:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{   


    if( argc != 2)
    {
     cout <<" Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
     return -1;
    }

    Mat image;
    image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file

    if(! image.data )                              // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow( "Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.
    imshow( "Display window", image );                   // Show our image inside it.

    waitKey(0);                                          // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

After that, every `.dll` was found, except this one: `"C:\Windows\System32\nvinitx.dll"`. How i am able to solve this? I found out, that this `.dll` is the driver of my NVIDIA GeForce GTX 660M.

Comment: Windows 8 or 7? Have you tried updating the driver of your GPU? Let me know after you tried updating it or have updated it and the error still persist.

Comment: Windows 7. Already tried an driver update, but it seems to be the actual version.

Comment: Also check if you using the right one, x32 or x64. It's a longshot, but have you tried adding it into your PATH? Then reopening the program?

Comment: x64 in usage. Added to path. nothing. -.-

Comment: Does this happen right after you try to execute your program? Does the error message come before a breakpoint is hit in your main? You need to find out somehow what relies on this dll as a dependency.

Comment: You can use Dependency Walker (depends.exe and depends64.exe), or disassemblers to discover the dependencies of your executable.